# RegEx: find a specific string enclosed in double quotes

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
<img src="/images/site_graphics/newsite/foo_com_logo.png" alt="foo.com" width="82" height="14"/>
```

What is the regex to match only the string within double quotes that start from src= ?

Comment: Something like this `src="(.*?)"`?

Comment: Tryed this \ssrc="(.*)" but it maches everything

Comment: Thanks @MarcoLuzzara

Comment: .* is greedy so it will select until the last double quote. Rather use [^"]* That will stop at the first double quote. Another option is .*? which stop at the first match

Answer (score 0):

## Forward

It's not advisable to use a regex to parse HTML due to all the possible obscure edge cases that can crop up, but it seems that you have some control over the HTML so you should able to avoid many of the edge cases the regex police cry about.

## Description

This regular expression

```regex
<img\b(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\ssrc=['"]([^"]*)['"]?)(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"\s]*)*"\s?\/?>
```

[image]
<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

Will do the following:

- This regex captures the entire IMG tag
- Places the source attribute value into capture group 1, without quotes if they exist.
- Allow attributes to have single, double or no quotes
- Can be modified to validate any number of other attributes
- Avoid difficult edge cases which tend to make parsing HTML difficult

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/qW9nG8/16

**Sample text**

Note the difficult edge case in the first line where we are looking for a specific droid.

```html
<img onmouseover=' if ( 6 > 3 { funSwap(" src="NotTheDroidYourLookingFor.jpg", 6 > 3 ) } ; ' src="http://website/ThisIsTheDroidYourLookingFor.jpeg" onload="img_onload(this);" onerror="img_onerror(this);" data-pid="jihgfedcba" data-imagesize="ppew" />
some text

<img src="http://website/someurl.jpeg" onload="img_onload(this);" />
more text
<img src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:BH_LMC.png"/>
```

**Sample Matches**

- Capture group 0 gets the entire IMG tag
- Capture group 1 gets just the src attribute value

```
[0][0] = <img onmouseover=' funSwap(" src='NotTheDroidYourLookingFor.jpg", data-pid) ; ' src="http://website/ThisIsTheDroidYourLookingFor.jpeg" onload="img_onload(this);" onerror="img_onerror(this);" data-pid="jihgfedcba" data-imagesize="ppew" />
[0][1] = http://website/ThisIsTheDroidYourLookingFor.jpeg

[1][0] = <img src="http://website/someurl.jpeg" onload="img_onload(this);" />
[1][1] = http://website/someurl.jpeg

[2][0] = <img src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:BH_LMC.png"/>
[2][1] = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:BH_LMC.png
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  <img                     '<img'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^>=]                    any character except: '>', '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ='                       '=\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ="                       '="'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^'"]                    any character except: ''', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^\s>]*                  any character except: whitespace (\n,
                               \r, \t, \f, and " "), '>' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*?                      end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    src=                     'src='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ['"]                     any character of: ''', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ['"]?                    any character of: ''', '"' (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^>=]                    any character except: '>', '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ='                       '=\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ="                       '="'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^'"\s]*                 any character except: ''', '"',
                             whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s?                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                           (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/?                      '/' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\ssrc\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"
```

The result will be in group 1.

Explain:

`\s` : Whitespace

`*` : Any amount of character

`[^"]` : Not double quote

`( )` : Group